# What is the minimum measurable mass?

Tags: mass, mass-energy

What is the minimum amount of mass that we can measure with today's equipment?

Can we measure the mass of electron with classical methods but without using the mass-energy equivalence?

Comment: This is fairly unclear about exactly what you want. Do you mean what is the smallest absolute mass, the smallest mass difference? Measured relative to what? Would you accept AMS-type measurements?

Comment: @JonCuster  knowing position, momentum limited by the uncertainty princoiple. Can uncertainty in mass similarly be expressed? I would suppose so since mass, equivalent to energy. Maybe that's what the OP intended to ask?

Comment: Consider how you'd design a CRT oscilloscope. As an intermediate step, you'd need to measure the electron mass (using the prototype oscillosc0pe) to know how to scale the voltage on the deflector plates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on what you are willing to accept as a measurement. The smallest masses we measure always come from "indirect" experiments.

For example, various experiments put incredibly tiny upper bounds on the mass of the photon using the fact that Maxwell's equations are different for a photon with mass. By comparing experimental results with the predictions of the modified Maxwell's equations we can put bounds on the mass. Modern experiments of various kinds can rule out anything above $10^{-18}\,\text{eV}/\text{c}^2$.

Neutrinos are the next most massive thing we know after the photon, but those measurements are also indirect. We can currently measure neutrino masses via their tendency to change flavor as they travel. However, this type of experiment really only measures differences between squared masses, rather than the masses directly. If you measure enough mass differences you can in theory calculate what the actual masses are, but we are not yet at the point where we know exactly what the masses are, but in all the possible scenarios the masses are less than $\sim 0.1 \text{eV}/\text{c}^2$

One currently intriguing hypothesis for the nature of Dark Matter is that it is a low mass axion, and various experiments have been built to investigate this scenario. No such particle has been found so far, but for example ADMX could in principle detect a particle with a mass as low as $10^{-6} \text{eV}/\text{c}^2$ using the tendency of the axion to decay into microwaves in a resonant chamber.

If these sorts of bounds and measurements aren't what you are looking for you will have to specify what type of mass measurement you are looking for.